# Encountering errors when replacing JPanels

Tags: java, swing, replace, jframe, jpanel

I'm in the process of creating a menu with several panels that are removed/added as the user navigates by clicking on buttons.

After trying various things, I came to one that made the most sense to me but gives me errors.

My error-producing "solution":

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source == jButton1) {
        changePanels(jPanel1, singlePanel1);
    }

}

public void changePanels (JPanel a, JPanel b) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add(b);
    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

For some reason, it produces these errors:

```
$Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1041)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:365)
at phantasma.OriginalFrame.changePanels(OriginalFrame.java:156)
at phantasma.OriginalFrame.actionPerformed(OriginalFrame.java:149)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I've run through various troubleshooting, but I'm not sure what the issue is. Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Following up on Russ's comment: Try creating a blank sandbox application and just swapping two panels that you *know* are not `null` using this method. See if it works or not.

Comment: Once you fix the NPE, use a `CardLayout`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was indeed null, and my solution is actually a solution now :D
EDIT: What are the advantages to a CardLayout? I don't think I can use that, since I have a special situation - I used a GridBagLayout because I needed to use buttons on top of a JLabel (my background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NullPointerException is one of the easiest problems to diagnose, because it tells you the source file and the line number at which it occurs.

In your case, it's

```
phantasma.OriginalFrame.changePanels(OriginalFrame.java:156)
```

Open your IDE, go to that line, and look for dereferenced object references.  One of them is null; you assumed it wasn't.

If that's not enough, set a breakpoint and navigate to that spot in the debugger.  It'll tell you exactly what's null.

Once you figure that out, think about why that object isn't initialized properly and fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now! I analyzed everything about singlePanel1, and managed to figure out that it wasn't declared like I remembered it to be.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can't declare for `getContentPane()` is useless from Java5 and higher

2) is isn't there declared any `LayoutManager` (probably your case) then `JFrame` , `JDialog` or `JWindow` has by default `BorderLayout`, all another JComponents have got ba default `FlowLayout`

3) if is there `BorderLayout` and isn't there declared decision Area (CENTER, NORTH...), then `Component` is by default placed to the `CENTER` area

4) for switch between `JComponents` and only if is there used `BorderLayout`, is required call `only`

```
myContainer.add(someComponent, BorderLayout.DECISION_AREA);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

and in you case is only

```
add(someComponent);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: Hi, I used GridBagLayout, but I took your suggestion about the `getContentPane()` and also changed my `validate()` to `revalidate()`. Thanks!